# Get iframe xml content on IE9 using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, iframe

I am having a hard time to get the xml content of my iframe on IE9. On other browser, it is working well but the way it rendered on IE9 is my problem.

My iframe and it's content rendered on IE9:

```
<iframe name="myiframe' id="myiframe">
    <Namespace xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <Nodes>
            <node>
            <node>
        <Links>
    ........
```

The code that I use to get the content:

```
var iframe: HTMLIFrameElement = <HTMLIFrameElement>document.getElementById('myiframe');
var xml = iframe.contentWindow.document.firstChild.textContent;
```

When I tried to `alert` the `xml`, it is displaying only the content of the node, not including the node title, even the `<` and `>`.

I need the xml string value. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Actually that is invalid as per your markup, you have put the nodes between the opening/closing of `iframe` and that only executes if any browser doesn't  support iframes. [An example of iframe @MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)

Also getting text content from `iframe` is also actually depends on [Same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

`.textContent` is doing correct thing to get the text of the element you are targeting. If you want to get the `html/Node` of the element you are targeting then you should use `outerHTML`:

```
var xml = iframe.contentWindow.document.firstChild.outerHTML;
```

Comment: Property `outerHTML` does not exist on type `Node`

Comment: `iframe.contentWindow` is actually a document which is loaded within the `iframe` with a `src` attribute and those content can be used to get the `outerHTML` to get the specific node with content.